# How to pass answers to bash script (composer-rest-server) options through text file?

Tags: bash, shell, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

This a question regarding composer-rest-server which opens a terminal & accepts user input for initialisation. For running the apps created using hyperledger one should launch **composer-playground** and **composer-rest-server**. Now consider the scenario where in we have to run the app in the server. For that we need to run both as a background service. The **nohup** option works for the composer-playground as there is nothing for the user to give as input but this fails in the case of the composer-rest-server where the user needs to give input as shown in the picture below:

[image: Normal running]

Now I tried to run this as a background service by passing the answers to the options through a text file. Each line of the text file will have the options which I type in the terminal.

```
admin@test-network
^[[B ^[[A \n
n
n
n
n
n
n
```

The first option works fine but I am stuck in the second option which is to select the **"always use namespaces"** from the multiple choice.

[image]

In normal running, after typing the first option(admin@test-network) I would press enter key to select the first choice from the multiple choice(of the second option) and then move on towards the remaining options. I have tried passing the following for the second option:

- New line character `\n`.
- Carriage return `\r`.
- Simulate down keystroke `^[[B` & up keystroke `^[[A` to come back to the first choice and pressing enter by passing `\n`.

Nothing seems to be working. Can anyone give suggestions on how to bypass this or another efficient way ?

Answer (score 0):

Use command `composer-rest-server -c <card name> -p <port number>` Hope it helpful

Comment: But isn't that command used to restart the rest server? My doubt is how to start the server provided you are given a headless server. For gui based vm like in Amazon EC2 its fine. You can use remote desktop to access it and then start the terminal and keep it minimised. But in the case of headless, as soon as the terminal shut off / internet gets disconnected in the client machine it gets disconnected. Not truly a background service.

Comment: nohup composer-rest-server -c <card name> -n always -w true -p <port number> > rest-server.out 2> rest-server.err < /dev/null &